# How to bind messages in javafx without using eclipse.osgi NLS?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a messages.properties file that contains all string messages used in my application.
I would like to bind these messages to a java class fields and use directly in other classes.

Can this be achieved without using NLS? By some approach in javafx? Because I do not want to add eclipse dependency in UI classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java provides property file reading capability right from the box. You can do adjustment to suit your actual use-case.

For example:

```
public final class Messages {
    private Messages() {
        loadFile();
    }
    private static final class ThreadSafeSingleton {
        private static final Messages INSTANCE = new Messages();
    }
    public static Messages getInstance() {
        return ThreadSafeSingleton.INSTANCE;
    }


    private final Properties props = new Properties();

    private void loadFile() {
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("messages.properties");
            props.load(is);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getMessage(String key) {
        if (key == null && key.isEmpty()) return "";

        return props.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

#### Edit

In order to use these values as if it is a constant, you need to pretty much make everything static:

```
public final class Messages {
    private Messages() {} // Not instantiable

    private static final Properties props = loadFile(); // Make sure this static field is at the top

    public static final String FOO = getMessage("foo");
    public static final String BAR = getMessage("bar");

    private static Properties loadFile() {
        final Properties p = new Properties();

        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("messages.properties");
            p.load(is);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return p;
    }

    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        if (key == null && key.isEmpty()) return "";

        return props.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Be warned again, the `Properties` field must always be the top-most field declared in the class, because the class loader will load the fields top-down for all static fields whose value is computed at runtime (i.e. set by a static method).

Another point, this example does not handles what happens if the file is not file - it simply returns a `Properties` that has no value.

Comment: I would rather like to access something like Messages.STRING_ONE . Is there any way other than this ?